# IE7 and dojo onchange of radio buttons fires too late?

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-7, dom-events

I have a page which has a form and say 3 input radio-buttons and I want to run some code when any of them are changed, so my code looks like this

```
dojo.query("#ze_form > input:radio").onchange(function () {
    alert("onchange fired!");
}
```

this works fine in normal web browsers, but in IE7 the alert is displayed only after clicking on a radio button, *then clicking outside* somewhere! It fires when it looses focus it appears!

Notice: in the console and previously doing alerts and stuff, I can see that my query selector does in fact select the correct radio buttons.

What is this strange phenomenon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 doesn't fire the `onChange` event until the radio button loses focus.  Your alternative is to connect to the `onClick` event.

Comment: Yep, I went with that alternative. Strange though, why doesnt ie fire the onchange as it should, its not like its called onloosefocus?